# Hangfire CRON in UTC time

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cron, hangfire

I am trying to configure a recurring task in my MVC application starting at 00:00 every day. I know this can be achieved by `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Easy!"), Cron.Daily);`.
Now my question is does hangfire cron work on basis of UTC time or the local time at server. If it works on local time, is there a way to run that on UTC time? I have to do this because this will be a day end process and all the scheduled tasks are scheduled based on the Universal time in my database.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

To execute a job in `UTC` time zone, you can provide `TimeZoneInfo` as `TimeZoneInfo.Utc` while defining your jobs.

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.Write("Easy!"), Cron.Daily, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
```

To execute a job in local time zone you can use `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.

Answer (score 15):

To run in a specific timezone instead of UTC, look up the `TimeZoneInfo` you want.

This task will run at midnight IST.

```
var manager = new RecurringJobManager();
manager.AddOrUpdate("some-id", Job.FromExpression(() => Method()),
    Cron.Daily(),
    TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time"));
```

Answer (score 5):

As `@Arun Prasad E S` answer is correct, but it gives obsolete warning, so need to change as given below,

```
var timeZoneOptions = new RecurringJobOptions();
                timeZoneOptions.TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

var manager = new RecurringJobManager();
manager.AddOrUpdate("some-id", Job.FromExpression(() => Method()),
    Cron.Daily(),
    timeZoneOptions );
```

Warning Message : warning CS0618: 'RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(Expression, string, TimeZoneInfo, string)' is obsolete: 'Please use an overload with the explicit recurringJobId parameter and RecurringJobOptions instead. Will be removed in 2.0.0.'

Answer (score 0):

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => 
   homeCtrl.SendEmail(), Cron.Daily(), 
   TimeZoneInfo.Local);

// 12:00:00 AM
```